# Rails 3 : How to include actions based on roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, include

I've got different roles on my RPG website. Each user can have many roles and based on this can access features. Let's say for instance a user is a teacher and director, he should access a page to manage his subjects and another to manage all the website.

Some people have more than 5 roles and it becomes really awkward to have 5 links to each office in the header.  How can I have an action to include others based on roles ?

In fact, I want to show all the offices available for a user on a unique page including offices managed by single actions. How is this possible ?

Thank you in advance !

PS: Actions are in different controllers

Comment: I recommend adding more detail to your question. Perhaps give us an example of a user with roles, and what those roles allow him to access on the site. Also, could you explain what you mean by 'office'; I can't tell from the question. Good luck.

Comment: In fact, I just want to include other actions if something is true. My question is just about including those actions in a unique page, I know how to handle the rest.

Comment: I've read and re-read your question and cannot understand what you are asking. I would include your class structure and a concrete example of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking either. An "action" has a very specific meaning in the context of Rails, so are you really referring to controller actions? If not, please restate the question so we know what you'd like to include where. Links to actions? Partials?

Comment: My problem is now solved. I was searching for a way to render pages in another page, something like partials but not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right.

I think it sounds like a user's privilege problem. If it is, I recommend Ryan's gem "CanCan". It's super easy to use.

[CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

And its Railscast: [#192 Authorization with CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)

Answer (score 0):

Make a chain of command, with role-weights. The heaviest role merges a lot of somehow related small ones.

Comment: There is no heaviest role since all are quite independent.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) gem which has a way of constraining database operations based on roles.

Example from [docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/fetching-records):

@articles = Article.accessible_by(current_ability)